# Missing data's while reading from serial port

Tags: visual-studio, serial-port

I am trying to read data from serial port in Win32. I used to open serial port. "ReadFile" is the API I used to read data from serial port, I am missing data while reading from the port. May I have a solution for the above issue.
I tried "ReadFile(hSerial, (char*)buffer, buffersize, (DWORD*)(&dwBytesRead), NULL);", I am getting datas, but I have datas missing.

Comment: Is there any serial port configuration that happens? I remember from a Linux based system that the setup/configuration of the serial port had some flags, among other things to ignore certain specific bytes (ASCII control characters) ...

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a minimal sample of your code + the input and the output (where you have missing data).